# Bigcommerce Stencil local dev can't access "/checkout.php" page

Tags: localhost, checkout, bigcommerce

I'm working locally using the Stencil API on the Cornerstone theme. When I try to navigate to "localhost:3000/checkout.php" the page will not load.

I have tried:

```
$ stencil start

$ stencil start -n

$ stencil start --tunnel
```

The page still refuses to load.

I have tried as an authenticated in user and as a guest.

All other pages on the site have been loading fine, and I haven't encountered any issues that would suggest an issue with my API key or access to my store's database.

Comment: Hey Mike, did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Comment: @Lansana Currently BC does their checkout entirely with their Blueprint framework, so any files related to the checkout process aren't available for direct editing within local Stencil dev. Knowing BS I would imagine they are planning to incorporate a Stencil driven checkout in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge!